# Names of the elements of the tuple declared with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code snippet:

```
{
    // Arrays declaration and filling
    string[] categories = CategorySelection.SelectedData[0].Select(x => x.Content).ToArray();;
    double[] values = = new double[ValueSelection.Height];
    for (int i = 0; i < ValueSelection.Height; i++)
    {
        values[i] = double.Parse(ValueSelection.SelectedData[0][i].Content);
    }

    var grouping = categories.Select((x, y) => (x, values[Array.IndexOf(values, x)]));
}
```

Variable `grouping` is declared as an `IEnumerable<(string x, int)>`, hence, the elements of the `Tuple` are `string x` and `double Item2`. Why doesn't the second element get a name like `y` from the lamba in LINQ expression?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the `Select` value and index lambda parameters and the creation of a value tuple

Comment: From the docs, selector `Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>`
A transform function to apply to each source element; **the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element**. -- The first part `(x, y) =>` isn't a value tuple, its just the parameters of the selector func. Although you have deleted your comment, thats why your tuple doesn't have `y` name property

Comment: Yep, I got confused with the index parameter from lambda and a tuple value. However, @Rawling gave a detailed answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples) isn't 100% explicit on what is used to infer names for tuple members, but it's basically because your first part has a named variable and your second part doesn't (it's using the result of an indexer).

> Beginning with C# 7.1, the field names for a tuple may be provided from the variables used to initialize the tuple. This is referred to as tuple projection initializers.
>
> ...
>
> In general, tuple projection initializers work by using the variable or field names from the right-hand side of a tuple initialization statement.

However, it does also tell you how you can do this manually:

> You create a named tuple by specifying the names for each element. One way is to specify the names as part of the tuple initialization:
>
> ```
> var named = (first: "one", second: "two");
> ```

so if you want `x` and `y` you should be able to use

```
var grouping = categories.Select((x, y) => (x, y: values[Array.IndexOf(values, x)]));
```

Comment: That's what I got confused by, the `x` name of the resulting tuple came from it's name in the lambda

Answer (score 0):

The overload [`Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__), which you are using - does not provide any name for the **projected** element, but for the **index** of the current element. Thus in your case `y` refers to the index of that element. What you´re doing with the element at that position has nothing to do with that index.

You´re just accessing an element from an array `values[...]`, which returns a `double`. As you didn not provide any name for it, the compiler creates one for you, which is `Item2`.

Let´s look into what your statement actually is under the hood. In fact you could also use this loop:

```
for(int y = 0; y < categories.Length; y++)
{
    string x = categories[y];
    yield return (x, values[y]);
}
```

You see `y` is only the **index** of the current element. It has nothing to do with the name of any of the element within the projected tup.e